# Build: '(' expected in *.d.ts files. Cannot compile TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to build my Angular 2 TypeScript asp.net core project in Visual Studio 2015, but what I see is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\core\esm\src\linker\query_list.d.ts 36
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\compiler\esm\src\output\output_interpreter.d.ts 7
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\compiler\esm\src\output\output_interpreter.d.ts 8
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\compiler\esm\src\output\output_interpreter.d.ts 9
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\common\esm\src\forms-deprecated\model.d.ts  53
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\common\esm\src\forms-deprecated\model.d.ts  98
>   Error TS1005  Build:'('
>   expected. MExplore    C:\Users\Piotrek\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MProjects\MExplore\wwwroot\lib\@angular\common\esm\src\forms-deprecated\model.d.ts  52

and so on...

So, the basic pattern of what those 3743 errors look like is:

> Build: '[something]' expected.

And files that problem happens always end with `*.d.ts`.

I thought that it was a problem with typings, but I have proper reference in my bootstraper (`main.ts` file)

```
///<reference path="./../../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
```

and those references inside:

```
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
```

I used it many times before and it worked...

I also use gulp ('gulp-typescript') to compile typescript to javascript and copy it to other place. It works well and no errors are shown. So maybe there are no problems with my code itself, but rather I configured something incorrectly in Visual Studio?

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

[According to this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4004), `*.d.ts` files should be excluded from compilation. So, basically, that's what you should do in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  [...]
  [some stuff]
  [...]
  "exclude": [
    "folder_where_you_have_those_faulty_files"
  ]
}
```

[Comment 1:](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4004#issuecomment-202358412)

> you should exclude some folders from tsc building to *avoid *to compile .d.ts files.

[Comment 2:](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4004#issuecomment-236077379)

> the key point is not compiling *.d.ts no matter which typescript version you use. in your project, you should exclude all of the *.d.ts compilation to get rid of this issue.

Thank you, @danny8002!

Comment: but tsconfig is mutually exclusive with CSProj, how do we exclude those files in a csproj!

Comment: I already have the node_modules folder inside the exclude array. But it includes it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error TS110 Build Typescript expected core.d.ts only when building Visual Studio. When Visual Studio builds it uses the tsc -w. This causes it to build all files *.ts under the directory and it doesn't distinguish between *.d.ts and *.ts, so will try to compile them. The *.d.ts files are type define files and can not be compiled. So you have to just tell ts to ignore node_modules folder.

You do this by adding the following **"exclude" : [ "node_modules","typings"]** to the tsconfig.json. You should always ignore these two folders.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules","typings"
      ]
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to have any effect. The error keeps occuring!